# Unicode strings returned by API not equal to my dict

Tags: python, json, unicode, boto3

So I'm trying to compare a dict that I have created to a dict response returned by a boto3 call.

The response is a representation of a JSON document and I want to check they are the same.

Boto3 always returned the strings as unicode.  Here's the response:

```
{u'Version': u'2012-10-17', u'Statement': [{u'Action': u'sts:AssumeRole', u'Principal': {u'Service': u'ec2.amazonaws.com'}, u'Effect': u'Allow', u'Sid': u''}]}
```

I initially created my dict like this:

```
default_documment = {}
default_documment['Version'] = '2012-10-17'
default_documment['Statement'] = [{}]
default_documment['Statement'][0]['Sid'] = ''
default_documment['Statement'][0]['Effect'] = 'Allow'
default_documment['Statement'][0]['Principal'] = {}
default_documment['Statement'][0]['Principal']['Service'] = 'ec2.amazonaws.com'
default_documment['Statement'][0]['Action'] = 'sts:AssumeRole'
```

However, when i compare these two dicts with == they are not equal.

So then I tried adding u to all the strings when I create the dict:

```
# Default document for a new role
default_documment = {}
default_documment[u'Version'] = u'2012-10-17'
default_documment[u'Statement'] = [{}]
default_documment[u'Statement'][0][u'Sid'] = u''
default_documment[u'Statement'][0][u'Effect'] = u'Allow'
default_documment[u'Statement'][0][u'Principal'] = {}
default_documment[u'Statement'][0][u'Principal'][u'Service'] = u'ec2.amazonaws.com'
default_documment[u'Statement'][0][u'Action'] = u'sts:AssumeRole'
```

This doesn't work either. The dicts are not equally and if i do a print of my dict it doesn't show u'somestring' it just shows 'somestring'.

How can I compare my dict to what boto3 has returned?

Comment: What happens when you drop down in a debugger and inspect the values individually and compare them?

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt works correctly in Python 2.7 and 3.3.  Below is just a cut-and-paste of your Boto3 response and your code (with document spelling corrected :)

```
D = {u'Version': u'2012-10-17', u'Statement': [{u'Action': u'sts:AssumeRole', u'Principal': {u'Service': u'ec2.amazonaws.com'}, u'Effect': u'Allow', u'Sid': u''}]}

default_document = {}
default_document[u'Version'] = u'2012-10-17'
default_document[u'Statement'] = [{}]
default_document[u'Statement'][0][u'Sid'] = u''
default_document[u'Statement'][0][u'Effect'] = u'Allow'
default_document[u'Statement'][0][u'Principal'] = {}
default_document[u'Statement'][0][u'Principal'][u'Service'] = u'ec2.amazonaws.com'
default_document[u'Statement'][0][u'Action'] = u'sts:AssumeRole'

print(D == default_document)
```

Output:

```
True
```